# How to keep ListView Item Selected when we navigate and again come on the same fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, selecteditem

I have one list view It is in Fragment. I am clicking the Item It is keeping it selected because i used the following code in listselected.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#646973" />
    </shape>

    </item>
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#646973" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_activated="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#646973" />
    </shape></item>

 <item android:state_accelerated="false">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#646973" />
    </shape>
 </item>
```

But when I go from One Fragment to another and when i again visit the same fragment it is then removed I want to do that. Please help me. The List View is filled dynamically when the OnCreateView is Created.

Comment: Do you want the list view to be displayed as it was before navigating to another fragment? I mean you do not want it to be removed?

Comment: I am setting list view adapter every time i come on the fragment. so i stored the position and changed the color every time but It selects more than one value. when i click.

Comment: Can you please show the code, I am not understanding exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're on the right track setting a drawable custom listview state. You also need to save the state of each row item (selected or not). If you post the code in getView(), then I can give sample code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem before. you can save your fragment state like this. save your view in the fragment.

```
View myLayout=null;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }

    if(myLayout==null){
        //initialize your layout here. 
         myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
    }
      else{
          try{

          ((ViewGroup)myLayout.getParent()).removeView(myLayout);

          }catch(Exception e){
              //an exception will be thrown when the very first time it trying to remove view from the parent
          }
     }

    return myLayout;
}
```